# how to connect Sqlcompact via. OleDbConnection

Tags: sql, oledbconnection

how to connect Sqlcompact via. OleDbConnection

my code:

```
        string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5; Data Source=C:\\newservice\\UserDataBase\\demo1.sdf;Password=MyPassword";
        conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dtTable = new DataTable("Record");
        OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from demo", conn);
        ada.Fill(dtTable);
        conn.Close();
```

i have got this error:

Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

how to solve this. wats the problem over here...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the format of your connection string is a little off. Try:

```
string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5; 
                  Data Source=C:\\newservice\\UserDataBase\\demo1.sdf;
                  SSCE:Database Password='MyPassword';";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the SQLCeConnection Class for this.

```
string connStr = "Data Source = Test.sdf; Password = <password>";

 SqlCeConnection conn = null;

try {
   conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
   conn.Open();

  SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "SQL HERE";

  //Change as needed
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

catch {
finally {
  conn.Close();
```